# Postgres-Repmgr node is marked as inactive after reboot

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-replication

I'm using using a cluster with 2 psql servers. I'm using repmgr to manage replication and failover.

Replication works fine, and when my master fail, the standby takes the lead. My problem is when I try to reup master as a slave. I use this commands:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main/*
repmgr -h acms-preprod-sql2 -U repmgr -p 5433 -d repmgr -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main standby clone
cp /var/lib/postgresql/recovery.template /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main/recovery.conf //recovery file for this node
service postgresql start
repmgr standby register --force --wait-sync
repmgrd -d --verbose >> /var/log/postgresql/repmgr.log 2>&1
```

But when I run the last command, I receive this message:

> [ERROR] This node is marked as inactive and cannot be used for failover

But when I try a cluster show, this node is register as stanby and is running So I don't understand wat's happening

Comment: any solution? beacuse for me it's the same